# Распознавание текста из изображения

Tags: java, распознавание-символов

Есть задача сдедать програму на java для распознавания кирилличного текста шрифтом семейства Times (без цифр и специальных символов) из картинок и его вывода. Сложность в том, что нельзя использовать библиотеки, которые решают эту задачу. Понимаю, что вопрос достаточно обширный, может есть у кого идеи или примеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шрифт известен, значит всё просто:

1. Нарезаем картинку на строки (если предполагается многострочный текст).
2. Нарезаем строки на связные области.
3. Если некая область не касается базовой линии текста, то объединяем её с областями, имеющими существенное пересечение по горизонтали. На этом шаге диакритические знаки должны объединиться с буквами, а составные знаки препинания в единое целое: `йё;:%`.
4. Опционально масштабируем к эталонному размеру (можно даже растягивать к фиксированному).
5. Каждую область сопоставляем с заранее заготовленными шаблонами букв. Могут понадобиться шаблоны лигатур, например, для "ft". В некоторых случаях понадобятся шаблоны частей символов: `№`. Выбираем то, что наиболее совпало.
6. Разбираемся с объединением частей символов, потенциально заменяем парные апострофы на кавычки.
7. Отдаём получившуюся строку.